# How does docker registry mirror works when request is from different CPU architectures?

Tags: docker

Suppose the below scenario:

I have a 64 bit server (if OS matters, it's Ubuntu, in general suppose it GNU/Linux) and have setup a registry mirror in this server.

All clients add this line to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
  "registry-mirrors": ["http://my_ip_v4_server:5050"]
}
```

Suppose client A's architecture is 64 bit, B's is 32-bit, C's is ARM, and D's is Apple M1.

Now what happens when each client runs `docker pull hello-world`? Suppose this image has multiple versions for different CPUs.

Client A gets 64-bit version of this image (it's normal and logical in my mind).

Does client B gets 64-bit version of this image? Or the registry mirror tries getting 32-bit to mirror that?

Regarding C and D, how do they work?

I do not have any other than 64-bit environment to test and see the logs.

Comment: If you want to support all those architectures, you should indeed make 1 image for each. Apple m1 is just ARM: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/multi-arch/

Comment: @Evert I'm not trying to add any image for other archs and do not intend to add any own image there. Mirror server works only to pull image from docker hub.